# How to trigger sibling component function from another sibling component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React I have a parent component with three sibling components, e.g.:

```
<div>
   <Component1/>
   <Component2/>
   <Buttons/>
</div>
```

I want to trigger functions defined in `<Component1/>` and `<Component2/>` from the `<Buttons/>` component. Currently I am using `useImperativeHandle` with `forwardRef` to export the functions from `<Component1/>` and `<Component2/>` and passing them to the `<Buttons/>` component via its `props`.

It works, but it doesn't seem the best way. What would be the recommended React pattern of doing this if I don't want to move `<Component1/>` and `<Component2/>` functions and state handling to the parent component?

Answer (score 2):

I would have suggested moving the state to the parent but since you prefer not to, you can use context with hooks

Creating the Context

`export const AppContext = React.createContext();`

Using it where needed (import the context and useContext prior)

`const {state, dispatch} = useContext(AppContext);`

Official doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: This feels even more hacky than the useImperativeHandle and forwardRef magic, nevertheless, I find the answer useful - I wasn't aware how easy is to (ab)use the context with hooks.